# I dont know why my discord bot cant read the messages?

Tags: python, discord, bots

well im making a discord bot for my server and it cant see when someone is typing something in general all tho everything seems to be fine the output stays 'mag_cecito#1080 said: '' (︱︱)'

```
from imaplib import Commands
import discord
import responces

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        responce = responces.handle_responce(user_message)
        await message.author.send(responce) if is_private else await message.channel.send(responce)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_disocrd_bot():
    TOKEN = 'MTAxNzcxOTYxNjQzMDE2MTkyMA.G6gR5I.DyNWFqtwynSFYLr5MyKTaJ3gC47ZjGNAcR8-YY'
    intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)
    client = discord.Client(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
    
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")
        
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

thats pretty much the code pls help

Comment: Assuming that is the real token you are testing with, I would see if I can change it out or generate a new one ASAP.

Comment: its a dummy so dont worry about the token

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a selfbot, then it's because you can't view messages in guilds using a selfbot as well as selfbots being unsupported in versions
bigger than `1.7.3`. If not then I'm guessing you can't run your token from a function. Just run your token from main.